# Minimize all windows on active monitor

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors

Does anyone know how to minimize all windows on the active monitor only in Windows 7? Or perhaps know of a program that does it?

I find it annoying when pressing <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> that windows on my second monitor gets minimized (I usually has an instance of foobar2000 always visible on it).

Comment: I have wrote my solution [here](http://superuser.com/a/1144293/662284). Hope can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some VB.NET code that can do this [here](http://vbcity.com/forums/t/163339.aspx). Not ideal, I know, but better than nothing. I don't know of another way to do this.

Comment: Thanks, that'll do fine. I'm rewriting it in a better language though ;)