# Is there a keyboard shortcut to minimise all windows on just one monitor?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts, windows-8

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Minimize all windows on the active monitor](https://superuser.com/questions/348423/minimize-all-windows-on-the-active-monitor)

It's quite widely known that <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> will minimize all windows (i.e. show the desktop), but there doesn't seem to be an equivalent for one monitor only.

Very often I will press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to open up some application from the desktop only to find the video player I have on my secondary monitor has been minimized as well. Due to bugs in the player, when I restore its window, the movie will either restart or the player and/or the display driver will crash.

Interestingly, in Windows 8, even though there are separate task bars (and start screens!!) for each monitor, the show desktop feature still works globally.

Solutions for either Windows 7 or 8 are acceptable.

Comment: It's not exactly a dup. Win+M still minimises all windows on both 7 and 8. The solution for that question requires a third party software that does "Multi-monitor Taskbar". I guess that won't be very attractive to a Windows 8 user.

Comment: That's why its labeled "possible duplicate" I am sure something more attractive will come along when W8 goes mainstream.

Comment: the question at http://superuser.com/questions/348423/minimize-all-windows-on-the-active-monitor has a 100+ rep .. isnt it supposed to be wrong then ?